Laravel Eloquent: Get data that respects a condition
I'm building a diet plan with Laravel 8; the database looks like this:



Recipes
Category
Calories




Apple pie
snacks
289


Banana pie
snacks
386


Tomato Pasta
lunch
712


Chicken Salad
lunch
756


Vegetables soup
dinner
410


Fish with potatoes
dinner
652



I'd like to randomly select the day's meals while placing an upper limit on the sum of the calories column.
For example, if my limit is 1500, I want to get a recipe from each of the 3 categories (lunch/dinner/snacks) whose total calories column does not exceed 1500.
How can I do this using Laravel Eloquent?

Retrieve all recipes for each meal category (snacks, lunch, dinner).
Calculate all possible combinations of recipes for each meal category.
Filter combinations where the total calories do not exceed the daily calorie limit.
Select one combination from each meal category to form a daily meal plan.

use App\Models\Recipe;

// Function to generate combinations of recipes
function generateCombinations($items, $n, $start = 0, $result = [], &$results = []) {
    if ($n === 0) {
        $results[] = $result;
        return;
    }

    for ($i = $start; $i < count($items); $i++) {
        $result[] = $items[$i];
        generateCombinations($items, $n - 1, $i + 1, $result, $results);
        array_pop($result);
    }
}

// Function to filter combinations by total calories
function filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCalories) {
    return array_filter($combinations, function($combination) use ($dailyCalories) {
        $totalCalories = array_sum(array_column($combination, 'calories'));
        return $totalCalories <= $dailyCalories;
    });
}

// Function to get daily meal plan
function getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories) {
    $mealCategories = ['snacks', 'lunch', 'dinner'];
    $mealPlan = [];

    foreach ($mealCategories as $category) {
        $recipes = Recipe::where('category', $category)->get()->toArray();

        // Generate combinations of recipes for this meal category
        $combinations = [];
        generateCombinations($recipes, 1, 0, [], $combinations);

        // Filter combinations by total calories
        $filteredCombinations = filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCalories);

        // If there are no valid combinations, choose a single recipe with the highest calories
        if (empty($filteredCombinations)) {
            $selectedRecipe = Recipe::where('category', $category)->orderBy('calories', 'desc')->first();
            $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedRecipe;
        } else {
            // Randomly select a combination from the filtered combinations
            $selectedCombination = $filteredCombinations[array_rand($filteredCombinations)];
            $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedCombination;
        }
    }

    return $mealPlan;
}

// Example usage
$dailyCalories = 1500;
$mealPlan = getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories);
print_r($mealPlan);

This code will generate a daily meal plan with recipes from each meal category (snacks, lunch, dinner) where the total calories do not exceed the specified daily calorie limit. If there are no valid combinations for a meal category, it selects a single recipe with the highest calories for that category.

Really nice! This method is more advanced and works perfectly. I learnt a lot with your functions. Thank you!

You should first give a threshold to your daily calories, and then when the query finds the random recipe, you should decrease the calories remaining by the number of the calories that this recipe has. Do this for each category.
$dailyCalories = 1500; //Calory limit threshold

$snack = Recipe::where('category', 'snacks')
    ->where('calories', '<', $dailyCalories / 3) // divide by 3 for a rough estimate
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();

$remainingCalories = $dailyCalories - $snack->calories;

$lunch = Recipe::where('category', 'lunch')
    ->where('calories', '<', $remainingCalories / 2) // Divide by 2 for a rough estimate
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();
$remainingCalories -= $lunch->calories;

$dinner = Recipe::where('category', 'dinner')
    ->where('calories', '<', $remainingCalories)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();


Very interesting and simple method! Some limits because I have to divide and some recipes will be excluded. Thank you for sharing!

Appreciate your feedback.

This will not select any snacks above 500 calories.
